# Sorting Arrays of Comparable Values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm developing a component that uses a key-based index that sorts items in a collection of referenced objects (an advanced dictionary).

The mechanism of comparison sorts well when the key is composed of one single item, but when to this I add the complexity of one more dimension I lose the precision of the sort.

```
var key1 = new Key{Values=new[]{23,56}};
var key2 = new Key{Values=new[]{23,58}};

// i will be -1 because the first component of key1 is equal to 
// the first component of key2
var i = key1.Compare(key2);
```

To obtain a sorting factor for the key I used an algebric addition of the comparison of the single components of the key.
I sense that I haven't done it right since the order is not respected when the values of the components have a higher degree of difference

```
var key1 = new Key{Values=new[]{23,92}};
var key2 = new Key{Values=new[]{33,45}};

// i will be 0 because the first component of key1 is less than 
// the first component of key2, but the second component of 
// key1 is more than the second component of key2, while I'd
// expect a -1
// -1 + 1 = 0
var i = key1.Compare(key2);
```

The sort is happening wrong because the whole components of the key are considered of equal importance, while I would like to rank the comparison factor by position

Has anyone faced the same situation? Am I missing anything?

**Note**: Consider that in my examples the values compared are numeric, but in reality the object types are variable, but all IComparable

Comment: can you give the compare method source code,  the solution to your pb is  there.

Answer (score 0):

Compare first component: if result is not zero return it. Otherwise, compare second component, return result.

This is called lexicographic order.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically iterate through all the fields and compare one by one in your comparator function something like this;

```
// Assuming A and B have same length 
bool comparator( const A[],  const B[]){
   for(i = 0 ; i < A.length; i++)
   if ( A[i] <= B[i])
   continue;
   else
   return true;

  return false;

}
```